Download WMS tiles in R Shiny for offline use
I would like to download WMS map tiles programmatically in R Shiny for offline use. I cannot use any third-party apps or tools; it has to be done in my code. I can use this map server, for example:
https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/WMSServer?
I am currently using Leaflet in R to display this map. Now I want to add the ability to download it.
Does anybody know a way to do this?
I tried this code but it simply displays a blank map. I think the problem is with my use of the gdal_utils function call. Are my options set properly? Is there a better library and function to use for this purpose?
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

wms_url <- "https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/WMSServer?"
txtService = "service=WMS"
txtRequest = "$request=GetMap"
txtVersion = "&version=1.3.0"
txtLayers = "&layers=0"
txtCrs = "&crs=epsg:4326"
txtBbox = "&bbox=0,0,50,50"
txtWidth = "&width=1024"
txtHeight = "&height=1024"
txtFormat = "&format=image/jpeg"
txtStyles = "&styles=default"
url = paste0(wms_url,txtRequest,txtService,txtVersion,txtLayers,txtStyles,txtCrs,txtBbox,txtWidth,txtHeight,txtFormat)

# Download the map data
output_file <- "C:/Projects/map_data.tif"
sf::gdal_utils(util='translate', source=url, destination=output_file, 
               options=c('-outsize', '1024', '1024', '-co', 'COMPRESS=JPEG'))

# Use the map data in Shiny
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width=6,htmlOutput("txtFromServer"),leafletOutput("mapFromServer")),
    column(width=6,htmlOutput("txtFromDownload"),leafletOutput("mapFromDownload")))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mapFromServer = renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addWMSTiles("https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/WMSServer?",layers="0")
  })
  
  output$mapFromDownload = renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles(urlTemplate = "C:/Projects/map_data.tif")
  })
  
  output$txtFromServer = renderUI({
    content = h3("Entire Map From the Server")
  })
  
  output$txtFromDownload = renderUI({
    content = h3("Map From the Download")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

This is the output I get:

When I do a preview of the file that was downloaded to my computer, this is what I get:


"Doesn't work" is a vague problem description. What in particular doesn't work? What does it do instead? Please [Edit] the Question.

The WMS URL is missing required parameters, (image format, WMS API version number, style, image size), uses the wrong case for parameter values it's GetMap not getmap, and WMS not wms,  and there is seemingly a mismatch between the spatial reference system specified and the bounding box, unless you want a very very small area.

I was actually looking for a very small area to start with, so the download size would be small. I had read that the capitalization was important but had not experienced that issue with the "GetCapabilities" function. Thanks for the heads up. I'm trying it now!

@nmtoken I made the edits that you suggested but there is still something wrong because the output appears blank.

I agree the generated request returns a blank image ~ https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&request=GetMap&version=1.3.0&layers=0&crs=epsg:3857&bbox=70,30,100,50&width=1024&height=1024&format=image/jpeg&styles=default that's nothing to do with the client

switching to EPSG:4326 (so the BBOX units becomes degrees lat/long, as opposed metres) however does give an image ~ https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&request=GetMap&version=1.3.0&layers=0&crs=epsg:4326&bbox=70,30,100,50&width=1024&height=1024&format=image/jpeg&styles=default so assume the issue is the server thinks your bbox is too small

So the image downloaded okay, although the projection needs adjusting. The problem with display of the image in Leaflet had partly to do with the file name. Map tiles should use the following naming convention: "z_x_y.png" where z is the zoom level and x and y correspond to the slippy map tile naming convention as described here.
output_file <- "C:/Projects/maps/1_0_0.png"
sf::gdal_utils(util='translate', source=urlWithParams, destination=output_file,
               options=c('-of', 'png', '-outsize', '1024', '1024'))

The other part of the problem is in the call to addTiles(). Again, the slippy map tile naming convention must be used. Also, specification of the min and max zoom levels is required.
outputPath = "C:/Projects/maps"
addResourcePath("test",outputPath)
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate = "test/{z}_{x}_{y}.png",
           options=tileOptions(minZoom=1,maxZoom=1))

Unfortunately, the zoom level is not something that can be specified in a single WMS URL parameter. The zoom level will be calculated according to the bounding box and the width and height requested.

xyz  tiles is nothing to do with WMS.  They are different specifications

The only way I can figure to use a WMS map offline is to download the map as xyz tiles and treat them like a tile server that happens to be located on your local machine. Do you know another way?
